# string convert matrix python

Tags: python, string, matrix, converters

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RefXk.png)how can i convert the following output to array or matrix.

Comment: What do you want to output to look like? Like a nested list where each line is subsequently split on spaces?

Comment: actually using output like multidimensional array which is exactly what it is looking for.navigating through the output as if using an excel columns.
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
Vlan1                  unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
Vlan5                  10.0.5.4        YES NVRAM  up                    up      
Vlan16                 unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up

Comment: Do you want a pandas dataframe (similar to an excel sheet) with columns: [interface,ipadress,ok?,Method,Status,protecol]?

Comment: yes how do i do that

Comment: Let me know if this helps you, if you run into any problems let me know I'll try to help you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to get it into a dataframe, I would do something like this.

```
import pandas as pd 

txt= """Interface IP-Address OK? Method Status Protocol
Vlan1 unassigned YES NVRAM administratively down down
Vlan5 10.0.5.4 YES NVRAM up up
Vlan16 unassigned YES NVRAM up up
Vlan19 172.16.205.205 YES NVRAM up up
Vlan33 172.16.33.4 YES NVRAM up up
Vlan41 192.168.11.4 YES NVRAM up up
Vlan192 192.168.10.4 YES NVRAM up up
Vlan200 192.168.3.4 YES NVRAM up up
GigabitEthernet0/1 unassigned YES unset down down
GigabitEthernet0/2 unassigned YES unset down down
GigabitEthernet0/3 unassigned YES unset down down
GigabitEthernet0/4 unassigned YES unset down down
GigabitEthernet0/5 unassigned YES unset up up
GigabitEthernet0/6 unassigned YES unset down down
GigabitEthernet0/7 unassigned YES unset down down
GigabitEthernet0/8 unassigned YES unset up up
GigabitEthernet0/9 unassigned YES unset up up
GigabitEthernet0/10 unassigned YES unset down down
GigabitEthernet0/11 unassigned YES unset down down
GigabitEthernet0/12 unassigned YES unset up up
GigabitEthernet0/13 unassigned YES unset administratively down down
GigabitEthernet0/14 unassigned YES unset down down
GigabitEthernet0/15 unassigned YES unset down down 
GigabitEthernet0/16 unassigned YES unset down down 
GigabitEthernet0/17 unassigned YES unset up up 
GigabitEthernet0/18 unassigned YES unset up up 
GigabitEthernet0/19 unassigned YES unset up up 
GigabitEthernet0/20 unassigned YES unset down down 
GigabitEthernet0/21 unassigned YES unset up up 
GigabitEthernet0/22 unassigned YES unset up up 
GigabitEthernet0/23 unassigned YES unset up up 
GigabitEthernet0/24 unassigned YES unset down down 
GigabitEthernet0/25 unassigned YES unset up up"""


#split endlines and subsequently split on spaces
#use filter(None,split_line) is used to remove any accidental lone spaces what would result in " "
split_text = [list(filter(None,line.split(" "))) for line in txt.replace("\r","").split("\n")]
#if split on spaces adminstarively up/down will be a problem as it would make for length 7, so if length 7 combine the words.
split_text = [[split_lines[0],split_lines[1],split_lines[2],split_lines[3],split_lines[4] + " "+ split_lines[5],split_lines[6]] if len(split_lines) > 6 else split_lines for split_lines in split_text]

#skip first line (as those are the columns) 
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(split_text[1:],columns=split_text[0])

print(dataframe.head(10)) #prints the first 10 elements
```

The output of the first 10 elements is this.

```
            Interface      IP-Address  OK? Method                 Status Protocol
0               Vlan1      unassigned  YES  NVRAM  administratively down     down
1               Vlan5        10.0.5.4  YES  NVRAM                     up       up
2              Vlan16      unassigned  YES  NVRAM                     up       up
3              Vlan19  172.16.205.205  YES  NVRAM                     up       up
4              Vlan33     172.16.33.4  YES  NVRAM                     up       up
5              Vlan41    192.168.11.4  YES  NVRAM                     up       up
6             Vlan192    192.168.10.4  YES  NVRAM                     up       up
7             Vlan200     192.168.3.4  YES  NVRAM                     up       up
8  GigabitEthernet0/1      unassigned  YES  unset                   down     down
9  GigabitEthernet0/2      unassigned  YES  unset                   down     down
```

Comment: how can i convert string output to literal

Comment: What is a literal?

Comment: I have attached a picture, may you take a look?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/literals-in-python/ So what do exactly you want?

Comment: I also solved the problem by adding this command. Thank you very much for taking the time to help.
sonuc=sonuc.replace("\r","")
sonuc=sonuc.strip("\n")

Comment: no problem, I'm glad you found out how to fix it :)